# Efficient way of calculating assignments per day with time span

Tags: javascript

I have a problem I'm trying to solve, but i feel I'm not solving it in the most efficient way. Any new light on this is appreciated.

This is the time span i want to look at

```
start = '2013-01-01';
end = '2013-01-08';
```

There is a list of assignments with start and end dates

```
assignments = [{start: '2013-01-01', end: '2013-01-01'},
               {start: '2013-01-01', end: '2013-01-02'},
               {start: '2013-01-01', end: '2013-01-03'},
               {start: '2013-01-01', end: '2013-01-04'}];
```

I want to end up with a result, each date in the time span with a value that represents how many assignments were active that day. This is what i want the result to look like:

```
result = [{date: '2013-01-01', value: 4},
          {date: '2013-01-02', value: 3},
          {date: '2013-01-03', value: 2},
          {date: '2013-01-04', value: 1},
          {date: '2013-01-05', value: 0},
          {date: '2013-01-06', value: 0},
          {date: '2013-01-07', value: 0},
          {date: '2013-01-08', value: 0}];
```

My attempts include iterating through each date in daterange and checking how many assignments fall on that day. I have also tried going the other way, iterating through assignments and then its start and end dates, pushing a value into an array for each date.

Are either of those ways on the right path or is there a smarter more efficient way?

Note: I'm doing this using javascript with underscore and moment js for dates.

Comment: I just can't think of any other way of doing so - I really am stumped for a better method (I recreated your function manually and had to resort to for loops).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> iterating through assignments and then its start and end dates, pushing a value into an array for each date

Not sure if you mean the right thing here. Instead of pushing to an array, an object to map dates (as string keys) to their respective count (integer) should be sufficient. The fundamental aspect here is that you can directly address the counts by date (no looping).

> Are either of those ways on the right path or is there a smarter more efficient way?

Both are on the right path. Which of them is more efficient depends on your data, basically how sparse the assignments are distributed over your date range (or maybe even outside?).

```
Having
 a := number of assignments
 d := average duration of assignments (number of days per assignment)
 n := number of days in your range
then the runtimes would be
 O(a*d)    for iterating assignments and their duration
 O(a*d+n)  for that and building a result with all days
 O(a*n)    for iterating days and checking all assignments
```

Since your result structure is an array of the dates in the range, your first approach is probably the better fitting choice.

If you have really large datasets and maybe some assignments outside of your date range, then having the assignments sorted could give you additional benefits as you can easily filter out the irrelevant ones.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. I think i will have to find another way to make getting this result quicker, with caching etc.

Comment: Do you have an actual performance issue? If you would outline the details of your setup, I could improve my answer with an actual implementation